# Problemas com json e php listagem

Tags: php, json

tenho uma linha de código em json que vem de uma variavel e quero listar essa lista json para entrar em um banco de dados mas não consigo fazer a leitura.

$dadosSite = file_get_contents('site');

```
$Puxa_titulo = explode('<div class="gallery-content item-gallery__wrapper" data-gallery-id="default" data-full-images="[' , $dadosSite );
$Titulo = explode(']">' , $Puxa_titulo[1] );

 $json = $Titulo[0];

 echo $json;
```

o site retorna isso:

```
{"src": "foto1.jpg", "w": "1200", " h ":" 900 "}, {" src ":" foto2.jpg "," w ":" 1200 "," h ":" 900 "}, {" src ":" foto3.jpg "," w ":" 1200 "," h ":" 900 "}, {" src ":" foto5.jpg "," w ":" 1200 "," h ":" 900 "}
```

preciso ler esse json listar ele tentei fazer isso mas n deu certo

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($json); $i++) {
    echo "<div>SRC: " . $json[$i]->{'src'} . "</div>";
    echo "<div>w: " . $json[$i]->{'w'} . "</div>";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Você já realizou o json_decode? Para transformar o json num objeto possível de ser utilizado pelo php.

Comment: não sei fazer isso

Comment: posta exatamente o que o $json retorna.

Comment: {"src": "foto1.jpg", "w": "1200", " h ":" 900 "}, {" src ":" foto2.jpg "," w ":" 1200 "," h ":" 900 "}, {" src ":" foto3.jpg "," w ":" 1200 "," h ":" 900 "}, {" src ":" foto5.jpg "," w ":" 1200 "," h ":" 900 "}

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta, tenta aí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca assim:

```
$Puxa_titulo = explode('<div class="gallery-content item-gallery__wrapper" data- 
gallery-id="default" data-full-images="[' , $dadosSite );
$Titulo = explode(']">' , $Puxa_titulo[1] );

$json = $Titulo[0];
$json = json_decode(html_entity_decode($json));
```

E muda o loop para a seguinte forma:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($json); $i++) {
  echo "<div>SRC: " . $json[$i]->src . "</div>";
  echo "<div>w: " . $json[$i]->w . "</div>";
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: ele não lista nada

Comment: Tenta novamente da forma que coloquei o loop agora.

Comment: continua sem retornar nada

Comment: Utiliza o print_r pra verificar como fica o $json após o json_decode, pra podermos entender o problema

Comment: continua sem retornar nada

Comment: Está retornando algum erro? Ou está conseguindo visualizar algo após inspecionar os elementos?

Comment: nada fica tudo em branco

Comment: Resolvi. a solução foi colocar o html_entity_decode no $json, as aspas estavam virando &quot então o json n conseguia converter.

Comment: $json = json_decode(html_entity_decode($json));

Comment: Ótimo Leandro, editei a resposta, se possível coloca a resposta como correta para finalizarmos essa pergunta.